# How to delete file that is listed in listbox?

Tags: c#

I use this code to list all .jpg files from folder into listbox

```
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.jpg");
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
```

After this I print the file with this code

```
        Image img = Image.FromFile(fileToPrint);
        Point loc = new Point(0, 0);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, loc);
```

and

```
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
        pd.Print();
```

And when I try to delete an item that is listed in the listbox with this code

```
        File.Delete(folder + "//" + listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

When I try to delete the file with selecting the file I get error message that the file is open.
How can I close the file or disengage it?

Comment: The code above is not responsible for your file being open. Do you have other code that accesses the files?

Comment: added code I use now

Comment: there must be pd.Close() or pd.dispose() to close the document.

Comment: `PrintDocument` does not have a `Close()` method, nor does it implement `IDisposable`. It's the `Image` that needs to be disposed.